# Working with monster.co.uk WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am a learner developer working on a project where I am required to post vacancies from our `.Net` based website to [monster.co.uk](http://doc.monster.com/real-time-posting) but I have no idea as how to achieve this. This is my virtually my first project of XML (WSDL) integration. Here is what I have tried so far:

- Create a reference to the desired WSDL file from **monster.co.uk** which is exposed at http://schemas.monster.com/current/WSDL/. But once the the objects are created in my Visual Studio project, I get stuck and don't know how to proceed from there. I consulted a couple of folks I thought may be able to help but in-vain. The documentation from monster is available from here http://doc.monster.com/real-time-posting.

I know I am asking for really basic stuff and should have been able to sort it out myself but have wasted 3 weeks and am no where. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read it in detail but from the second link with the documention my approach would be:

> -Decide which Real Time Posting features to implement by reviewing the "Development Considerations" section of this guide.

Read the section and decide what are you going to use

> ```
> Create the XML job posting by using the instructions in this guide and samples located in Monster's webservices toolkit
> ```

It seems you'll have to create a xml. First thing comes to mind is using a XmlDocument object and adding Nodes to it. But you may want to check other answers as there's different ways to do this. Create the xml in the format specified by Monster, you can check the samples they give to know how to do it

> ```
> Validate XML using the toolkit.
> ```
>
> (http://integrations.monster.com/Toolkit)

Go to the toolkit ulr and input the xml you are generating to check is correct

> ```
> Test posting a job from your application (Applicant Tracking System, etc).
> ```

You do this calling methods from the Web service(e.g.: UpdateJobs) with your generated xml

> Review the job posting response, make the necessary changes and
>   retest.

Check the testing section at the end. It says you can post into the demo board for you test.

> ```
> Once the test cycle is complete, transition to production using the steps outlined in the "Deployment" section of this guide.
> ```

Once you are happy with the testing in UAT read this to know how to release to production.

--

EDIT to add more info after question was clarified

I understand the problem now. I added a Web service reference to https://gateway.monster.com:8443/bgwBroker and in the object that returns I can see a lot of data structures. However I was able to find a `BusinessGatewayInterface` that has the needed operations. Check the code below. I am sure it is not what you need but it may give you an idea of what to do. Then it will be an issue of exploring the Web service reference until you find what you need.

Also it seems it won't be needed to parse the xml directly but instead there are typed data structures that can be populated. Sorry I didn't realized that the first I looked into it

```
    Job job = new Job();

    UpdateJobRequest updateJobRequest = new UpdateJobRequest();

    //populate job info here
    updateJobRequest.Job = job;

    ServiceReference1.BusinessGatewayInterface gateway = new BusinessGatewayInterfaceClient();
    gateway.UpdateJob(updateJobRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot TonyS. You have certainly replied patiently to what I assume is a bit silly question on my side. I have used the k2soap... library with and basic Android app and that library takes care of the soap formation etc. I just needed to call a method with the values (limited data) and it did everything it needed. Here though as you know exactly how to call the required method to submit the XML vacancy. I will explain this in the comment following what the problem is. Thank you again TonyS

Comment: TonyS, when I added a reference to the WSDL from monster in my project, there are numerous classes including the one 'UpdateJobRequest' with the default and one more constructor but no methods. This is where I get stuck as to how to pass the XML to this object/method. Thank you for you assistance.

Comment: No worries LiaqatG. Often it is just a case of finding that little link missing. I have edited my original answer and hope that helps you

Comment: Thanks again TonyS. I will give it a try and see where I get with it. The answer is already proving informative and helpful and I am positive I will be able to get closer to finding the answer. I will mark your reply as answer but keeping it open for other who may join in. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
        MonsterBusinessGatewayService gateway = new MonsterBusinessGatewayService();

        gateway.Url = "https://208.71.198.74:8443/bgwBroker";
        gateway.Proxy = proxy;
        proxy.Credentials = cre;
        gateway.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        gateway.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        gateway.Security = security;
        security.UsernameToken = user;
        user.Password = pass;

        gateway.Security.UsernameToken.Username = "xtestxftp";
        gateway.Security.UsernameToken.Password.Value = "ftp12345";

        Job job = new Job();
        JobsResponse jobresp = gateway.UpdateJob(job);
```

I'm working with Monster real time and I implemented this code to send request to Monster Business Gateway. May this can help also